# Are these two model definitions differ from each other?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Do these two model definitions differ from each other or do they work the same way?

And if these are different, why?

```
def create_model(input):

   x = Conv2D(256, 3)(input)
   x = ReLU()(x)

   x = Flatten()(x)
   x = Dropout(0.4)(x)

   x = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(x)
   model = Model(input, x)
   return model


def create_model(input):
   model=Sequential([

       Conv2D(256, 3, input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu' ),
       Flatten(),
       Dropout(0.4),
       Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')


   ])
   return model
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the model definitions are same. The only difference is the way you are defining i.e sequential and functional.